How to use Hugging Face model with 512 max tokens on longer text (for Named Entity Recognition)
I have been using the Named Entity Recognition (NER) model https://huggingface.co/cahya/bert-base-indonesian-NER on Indonesian text as follows:
text = "..."
model_name = "cahya/bert-base-indonesian-NER"
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
nlp = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy="simple")
entities = nlp(text)

This works great, but when text contains more than 512 tokens I get the error:

The size of tensor a (1098) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1

What is the best way to check if text contains more than 512 tokens, and then split it into manageable chunks that I can use for NER?

Counting the number of tokens seems straightforward:
n_tokens = len(tokenizer.encode(text, add_special_tokens=True, truncation=False))

However, it is unclear what is the best way to split this. Surely there should be a suite of functions for this?
